# Вывести несколько заголовков CSV через цикл for

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Например, у меня есть код, который выводит нужный мне заголовок:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',')
for line in a['header1']:
    print(line)
```

Но как мне вывести сразу два заголовка в цикле?

Пробовал что-то вроде:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',')
for line in a['header1','header2']:
    print(line)
```

Но выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: print(a[['header1','header2']]) ? Было бы проще отвечать если бы вы привели в вопросе пример результата, который вы хотите получить

Comment: В результате хочу что бы выводилось
`
textfromh1,textfromh2
`
И мне нужно что бы каждая строка выводилась поочерёдно с помощью цикла for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.itertuples()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples):

```
for row in df.itertuples():
     print(row.col1, row.col2)
```